# Unbounded opertor $S^*+T^*\subset (S+T)^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question in conway's functional analysis:For the unbounded operator in Hilbert space H,why

$S^*+T^*\subset (S+T)^*$,i.e. how to prove $\mathrm{Dom}(S^*+T^*)\subset \mathrm{Dom}((S+T)^*)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in \mathrm{Dom}(S^*+T^*) \iff x\in \mathrm{Dom}(S^*)\cap \mathrm{Dom}(T^*) \iff$ 
$(y\mapsto\langle x,Sy\rangle)$ and $(y\mapsto\langle x,Ty\rangle)$ are bounded $\ \ \implies$ 
$(y\mapsto\langle x,(S+T)y\rangle)$ is bounded $\iff x\in (S+T)^*$.

Comment: One more question: so why $T^*S^*\subset (ST)^*$

Comment: That's similar: if $x\in Dom(T^*S^*)$, that means $x\in Dom(S^*)$ and $S^*x\in Dom(T^*)$. Then for any $z$ we have
$$\langle T^*S^*x,z\rangle=\langle S^*x,Tz\rangle=\langle x,STz\rangle$$
which is bounded as lin.functional in $z$.

Comment: Hi Berci, it have being so many years, but I want to ask, why $x\in D(S^*)$ implies $(y\mapsto <x, Sy>)$ is bounded?

Comment: It's basically by definition. There's a representing vector $v=S^*x$ for the functional $y\mapsto \langle x, Sy\rangle$ iff that's bounded. (Riesz) Btw, the direction you're asking is immediate as \langle x, Sy\rangle =\langle S^*x, y\rangle$ which has norm $\le\|S^*x\|$ as function of $y$.

Comment: Oh, thank you, here the $x$ is fixed, thus the $|f(y)|\le\|S^*x\|\|y\|$ is bounded.